# Tips on understanding Ruby syntax, when to use ?, and unless

Tags: ruby

Is the keyword `unless` the same as `if`?

When do you use `?`?

I've seen:

```
if someobject?
```

I know it checks against nil correct?

Comment: Isn't this Rails-independent Ruby syntax?

Comment: well sometimes there are Rails specific conventions.

Comment: I've seen people get confused about the logic when using the unless keyword.  It's important to realize that 'if(a and b)' is equivalent to 'unless(!a or !b)' and not 'unless(!a and !b)'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is the keyword 'unless' the same as 'if' ?

No, it's the opposite.

`unless foo` is the same as `if !foo`

> ```
> if someobject?
> ```
>
> I know it checks against nil correct?

No it calls a method named `someobject?`. I.e. the `?` is just part of the method name.

`?` can be used in methodnames, but only as the last character. Conventionally it is used to name methods which return a boolean value (i.e. either true or false).

`?` can also be used as part of the conditional operator `condition ? then_part : else_part`, but that's not how it is used in your example.

Answer (score 2):

`unless` is actually the opposite of `if`. `unless condition` is equivalent to `if !condition`.

Which one you use depends on what feels more natural to the intention you're expressing in code.

e.g.

```
unless file_exists?
  # create file
end
```

vs.

```
if !file_exists?
  # create file
end
```

Regarding `?`, there is a convention for boolean methods in Ruby to end with a `?`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the convention for `?`-suffix is to use it when naming a method that returns a boolean value. It is not a special character, but is used to make the name of the method easier to understand, or at least I think that's what the intention was. It's to make it clear that the method is like asking a question: it shouldn't change anything, only return some kind of status...

There's also `!`-suffix that I think by convention means that the method may have side-effects or may modify the object it is called on (rather than return a modified copy). Either way, the `!` is to make you think carefully about calling such a method and to make sure you understand what that method does.

I don't think anything *enforces* these conventions (I've never tried to break them) so of course you could abuse them horribly, but your fellow developers would not be happy working with your code.

for `unless` see here: http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/12/01/unless-the-abused-ruby-conditional/

Answer (score 2):

This statement:

```
unless conditional expression
```

Is the equivalent to:

```
if not (conditional expression)
```

In Ruby you can end your method names with a question mark which is normally used to show that it is a boolean method.
With Rails a check against nil would look like this:

```
someobject.nil?
```

This calls the nil?() method of the object, which returns true for NilObject and false for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

```
if someobject?
```

The appending of a '?' here only means that it returns a boolean.